# Whenever an account name is modified send an email notification to the contact of an Account

Tags: before-trigger, after-trigger

Trigger is not go into the If Condition and Not compare Value.
How to comapare oldAccount Name is notEqual to ModifiedAccount Name?
And How to write query for the Id to compare the Name in the code.If anyother mistake by me please told me

```
trigger SendEmailtoContact on Account (before Update,after Update) {

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        List<String> Name = new List<String>();
       // Account ac = new Account();
    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
    List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();

     //  ac = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account];
    for(Account acc : trigger.old){
       // System.debug('accName::' + acc.Name);
    //   String oldName = String.valueof('acc.Id');
         //String oldName = trigger.oldmap.get('acc.Id').Name;
        **if(acc.Name != acc.Name){
            Name.add(acc.Name);
            System.debug('Name::' + Name);**
        }
    }

    if(Name.size()>0)
    {
        con = [SELECT lastname,E_mail__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN:Name];
        System.debug('----contact----'+con);
        if(con.size()>0){
            for(Contact c : con){
                sendTo.add(c.E_mail__c);
                system.debug('emali::'+sendTo);
            }
        }
    }

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Email Alert');

    mail.setSubject('Account Name change');
    String body = 'Dear Employee Account Name is change.';
    mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
    mail.setHtmlBody(body);
    mails.add(mail);
    try{
        Messaging.SendEmail(mails);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('-----Exception------' +e);        
    }
}
```

Error:Error:Apex trigger SendEmailtoContact caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: SendEmailtoContact: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: acc.Id: External entry point

Comment: Why not just use a workflow rule and email alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few changes that you need to make in order for this to work

- You need to identify in which context your mail should be triggered, as per your code it currently fires on before and after update. I would prefer to have it in after update context. So for that, you will have surround your code with a check for the after update.
- You are currently not comparing the `oldValue` and `newValue` in your code, instead you are just checking the same values which will never be true.
- You will have to get the `oldValue` from `Trigger.oldMap` context variable. And I see that you tried in the commented code which won't give you the old value. You can get the old value by using `String oldName = trigger.oldmap.get(acc.Id).Name` and not `String oldName = trigger.oldmap.get('acc.Id').Name`. Note that you will have to pass the Account's `Id` and you don't have to enclose your variable in single quotes.
- And the reason you are getting the above mentioned error is because you are trying to filter out the `Contacts` based on `AccountId` and you are trying to compare `AccountId` field with the `List` of Names, which again is not correct.

Below code should work for you

```
trigger SendEmailtoContact on Account (before update, after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Set<Id> setAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
        for(Account acc : trigger.New){
            if(acc.Name != trigger.oldmap.get(acc.Id).Name){
                setAccountIds.add(acc.Id);
                System.debug('setAccountIds::' + setAccountIds);
            }
        }

        if(!setAccountIds.isEmpty()) {
            for(Contact c : [SELECT lastname,E_mail__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN:setAccountIds]){
                if(string.IsNotBlank(c.E_mail__c)){
                    sendTo.add(c.E_mail__c);
                }
            }
        }

        if(!sendTo.isEmpty()){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Email Alert');

            mail.setSubject('Account Name change');
            String body = 'Dear Employee Account Name is change.';
            mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);
            mails.add(mail);
            try{
                Messaging.SendEmail(mails);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('-----Exception------' +e);        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting something inside `'` characters makes it a String. You want to use the variable itself:

```
String oldName = trigger.oldmap.get(acc.Id).Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for help